# Two dots above letter: amsmath error \hat allowed only in math mode

Tags: errors, accents

Trying to write the name `Fra\"{i}ss\'{e}` stylised correctly, I believe `\"{i}` is the correct way to get the two dots above the i but I get the following error:

```
Package amsmath Error: \hat allowed only in math mode
```

The output looks like this:

[image: Fraisse]

Not entirely sure what could be going wrong, assume it's something odd in my preamble but the \hat error confused me.

EDIT: okay this is an issue that would be unique to me and a poorly redefined function.

To elaborate, in my preamble I had `\newcommand{\i}{\hat i}` hence why the error mentioned `\hat`.

Comment: Without code, we can't even start to guess what's going on. It seems to me that you want write a text, so math mode shouldn't be involved at all?

Comment: `\"{i}` would result in three dots; it should (ordinarily) be `\"[\i}`.  But the error message about `\hat` isn't at all related.  Without a lot more information, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @barbarabeeton No, `\"i` is declare as a composite and will do the same as `\"{\i}`

Comment: The error message you received --   `\hat `allowed only in math mode -- indicates that you tried to input the word as `Fra\hat{i}ss{\'e}`. Is this hunch correct?

Comment: Hi all, you're right that there wasn't enough information to solve this problem as is - apologies.

Comment: You must have had an error for `\newcommand{\i}{\hat i}` telling you that `\i` is already defined, never ignore errors!

Comment: @egreg -- Okay, I have tested.  `\"i` and `\"{i}` *are* the same.  I'm still trapped in an earlier universe.

Comment: This has nothing to do with math, much less `amsmath`, so I am removing that lag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

If you are writing a name, you are not in math mode, so:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Fraïssé  Fra\"iss\'e
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You're right that this works, it was an issue buried in renewing commands.